# path to Desktop on Windows without having to know username

Tags: python

I'm use py2exe to create a .exe file so that someone without Python on their computer can run a script. Because I'm creating an alias (shortcut) of the .exe file, I need to hardcode the path to the folder containing the files that the python script targets. I also need to make sure that it will work on anyone's desktop (regardless of username) and work in a folder called Reports. I tried using the following line of code but I got an invalid syntax error:

```
cwd = r"os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Reports")"
```

I wondered if anyone could provide any advice to help solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I changed the inner double quotes to single quotes and tested again. The syntax error went away but it's now saying: WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: "os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/Reports')/*.*" Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this help you

```
desktop="c:\\users\\{}\\Desktop".format(os.getenv("username"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This works on my Windows installation:

```
>>> import os
>>> desktop = os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop'
>>> print(desktop)
C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Desktop
>>> cwd = os.path.expanduser('~\Desktop\Reports')
>>> print(cwd)
C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Desktop\Reports
```

**As a standalone script:**

```
import os
import csv2xlsx 


cwd = os.path.expanduser('~\Desktop\Reports')
print(cwd)

csv2xlsx.main(cwd + "\Report.csv", cwd + "\Report.xlsx")
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Desktop\Reports
```

Comment: #shash678  - thanks, I need to incorporate your code so that it can be included my variable cwd (as posted orginally). Can you show me how to do this as my Python skills are not that great.

Comment: @user3694360 Do you mean like that?

Comment: Yeah maybe. Do I need the C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Desktop part?

Comment: The first part is using the python Shell `>>>` indicates a line with python code, without it is the putput after entering that line.

Comment: You don't have the same code as mine. Look at your `cwd` line and try spot the difference?

Comment: Not use to using this forum but did you see my code posted in the previous comment? It's not formatted but you can see basically how the cmd variable is placed. How can I incorporate your code with this code block?

Comment: Try `cwd = os.path.expanduser('~\Desktop\Reports')` instead of `cwd = r"os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Reports")"`

Comment: I ended up using:     import os
    cwd = os.path.expanduser('~') + '\Desktop\Reports'

Comment: The error was:  with open(path, 'U') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\jkl\\Desktop\\Reports\\Report.csv'

Comment: Notice how it's inserting double backslashes?

Comment: I have the following at the end of my code:     import csv2xlsx
    csv2xlsx.main(r"C:\Users\jkl\Desktop\Reports\Report.csv", r"C:\Users\jkl\Desktop\Reports\Report.xlsx")

Comment: I need to use the same relative file path as you gave me but not sure how to edit this line. Can you help as it may help get rid of the error I mentioned.

Comment: Ok but how do I change the absolute path mentioned a couple of comments ago, to the relative path you gave earlier?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that revised comment. I just tested it and I now get the following error:     with open(path, 'U') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\jkl\\Desktop\\Reports\
\Report.csv'
Do you know why it's inserting double backslashes?

Comment: There is no revised comment.... look at the answer itself in the standalone script.

Comment: Thanks - I understand now.

Comment: Sorry just one final comment. Will  cwd = os.path.expanduser('~\Desktop\Reports') work on any computer as long as the person has a "Reports" directory on their desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the best with python, but I know that if you substitute this in your code, you'll get your Desktop directory.

*os.environ["HOMEPATH"]*

It might not work but substitute it in your code and try it out.
Good luck!